# How to perform operations over neighbourhoods of specific pixels in Halide?

Tags: halide

There are a number of specific pixels in an image around which I want to find the minimum local gradient. I can do this easily enough for all pixels in the image:

```
Func grad, gradmin;
grad(x, y) = pow(input(x+1, y) - input(x-1, y), 2) + pow(input(x, y+1) - input(x, y-1), 2);

RDom r(-1, 3, -1, 3);
gradmin(x, y) = minimum(grad(x + r.x, y + r.y));
```

But how does one do this for a set of specific pixels within in the image? If they are patterned, is it possible to do something like this?:

```
RDom r(-1, 3, -1, 3);
gradmin(x, y, i) = minimum(grad(x*f(i) + r.x, y*f(i) + r.y));
```

assuming (x, y) run from `(0 .. n, 0 .. m)`. The effect I'm going for is the same as incrementing a loop counter by a step greater than 1.

Also, is there a way to record what the x, y coordinates of the minimum gradient point were?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you do define the expression that accesses the coordinates.
To my understanding `grad(x*f(i))` should work. Have you tried it ?

Regardings the second question you can simply use the Halide [argmin](http://halide-lang.org/docs/namespace_halide.html#a6b42c8c37893bacb33261bdec53303d3) function.